# Java , XML User Verification Failure

Tags: java, xml

I've been trying to make this work for longer than I'd like to say now and just can't figure out why it won't recognize the password,I get a null pointer exception on this line    if (userPassword.getTextContent().equals(password)

Here is the method

```
public class XML {
    public static boolean login(String email, String password) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse("data.xml");
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList nList = root.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(i);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element users = (Element) nNode;
                if (users.getNodeName().compareTo("users") == 0) {
                    NodeList userList = users.getChildNodes();
                    for (int j = 0; j < userList.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node userNode = userList.item(j);
                        NodeList AttributeList = userNode.getChildNodes();
                        Node userPassword = AttributeList.item(1);
                        Node userEmail = AttributeList.item(0);
                        if (userPassword.getTextContent().equals(password)
                                && userEmail.getTextContent().equals(email)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what does your debugging say? like is AttributeList  null or?

Answer (score 0):

Attribute nodes don't have text content but a value. You should use the following construct to retrieve it :

```
Node userNode = userList.item(j);
String attributeValue = userNode.getAttribute("attributeName")
```

Alternatively since you already have the attributes `Node`s, you could cast them to `org.w3c.dom.Attr` and use their `.getValue()` method.